# Finding the correlation between variables using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, correlation

I am trying to find the correlation of all the columns in [this dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-white.csv) excluding `quality`and then plot the frequency distribution of wine quality.

I am doing it the following way, but how do I remove quality?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-white.csv', sep=';')
df.corr()
```

It returns this output:

[image]

How can I graph the frequency distribution of wine quality with pandas?

I previously used R for correlation and it worked fine for me but on this dataset I am learning use of pandas and python:

```
winecor = cor(wine[-12])
hist(wine$quality)
```

So in R I am getting the following output and I am looking for same in Python.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please reword what you are trying to achieve? Could you also post a sample picture of the histogram you want to get?

Comment: It is not clear where the numbers 3 through 9 come from. You do not have them anywhere in your dataset.

Comment: it is in the quality column, http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-white.csv

Comment: Image above in the question is after applying `corr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. Histogram

```py
# Import plotting library
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

### Option 1 - histogram
plt.hist(df['quality'], bins=range(3, 10))
plt.show()

### Option 2 - bar plot (looks nicer)
# Get frequency per quality group
x = df.groupby('quality').size()
# Plot
plt.bar(x.index, x.values)
plt.show()
```

#### 2. Correlation matrix

In order to get the correlation matrix of features, excluding `quality`:

```py
# Option 1 - very similar to R
df.iloc[:, :-1].corr()

# Option 2 - more Pythonic
df.drop('quality', axis=1).corr()
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried to clear my question more, I edit it, my major focus is on 2 parts, 1. `What is the correlation between the attributes other than Quality?` and `Graph the frequency distribution of wine quality by using Quality.`

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for clearing up the question. I edited my answer. Did that help?

Answer (score 1):

You can plot histograms with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

plt.hist(x=df['quality'], bins=30)
plt.show()
```

Read the docs of [plt.hist()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) in order to understand better all the attributes